# core-wars, how to replicate entire instructions

Tags: assembly, memory, corewars, redcode

I have tried these but no luck so far, next is equak to 200, move is dat 0, 200, tot_ins is 58,

```
relloc
    jmp 2
    aa dat 0, bomb -1
    relloc_begin
        mov @aa, @move  
        add #1, aa
        cmp @aa, tot_ins+1
        jmp relloc_begin
        sub tot_ins+1, aa
        jmp @aa+ne
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't think we need the redundant [redcode] tag.

Comment: @RossRidge : Corewars has two variants. Redcode and x86. The assembly language is different between them and Stackoverflow has a number of questions related to the x86 variant and the Redcode variant. Redcode is in itself a language. When paired with the assembly tag the [redcode] tags will identify to watchers which one it is.

Comment: @MichaelPetch So?  There aren't enough Codewar questions to warrant distinguishing them.

Comment: @MichaelPetch alright, thanks for adding the redcode tag.